# ActionView helper yielding with a parameter. Works in development mode but not production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is using Rails 3.0.10 and HAML 3.1.3, although this is also an issue when the same logic is used in an ERB partial.

I have a very weird situation where I have code that works as expected in development mode but dies badly in production mode.

I have a partial:

```
- @emails.group_by(&:day).each do |day, email|
  - email.each do |msg|
    =message_content_for_link(msg) do |content|  #loops here in production
      =link_to content, "#/email/#{msg.id}", :id => "message_#{msg.id}", :class => cycle('even', 'odd') + ' view_message'
```

message_content_for_link is defined in a helper thus:

```
  def message_content_for_link(msg, &block)
    content = msg.is_read ? [content_tag(:span, '', :class => 'read')] : [content_tag(:span)]
    content << content_tag(:p, h(msg.from), :class => 'from')
    content << content_tag(:p, truncate(h(msg.subject)), :class => 'subject')
    block.call content.join('').html_safe
  end
```

In development mode the above works as expected. In production, it dies badly as the code loops around =message_content_for_link(msg) do |content| until the server's memory is exhausted.

I've re-written the above in ERB but the effect is exactly the same.

```
<% @emails.group_by(&:day).each do |day, email|  %>
  <% email.each do |msg| -%>
    <%= message_content_for_link(msg) do |content| %>
      <%= link_to content, "#/email/#{msg.id}", :id => "message_#{msg.id}", :class => cycle('even', 'odd') + ' view_message' %>
    <% end -%>
  <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

I've got a feeling that I am missing something very obvious. Am I or is this a bug? Are there any suggestions for a workaround?

Again, my thanks for any suggestions, clues or hints.

EDIT: This is not a HAML issue the equivalent ERB code has the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just have a lot of emails in production?

Answer (score 0):

Might be the fact that you use "content" as a local variable and a param? Try renaming one of them to make sure there's absolutely no confusion between them.